# Why does 16.04 Files icon not have dots?

Tags: unity, nautilus, icons

I thought it was super odd that the files icon didn't have a number of dots corresponding to number of its windows open, as other apps do. Then today I realized that *way* at the bottom there was a files (nautilus) icon, that had the dots. So I moved it up near the other identical icon.

Is there a reason there are two showing up on my 16.04, should I hide/remove from panel the one that strangely has no dots?

Comment: No dots? Not sure what you mean. A screenshot?

Comment: The dot or dots to the far left on the screen, when windows of the app are open.